# How can a Github Gradle project built in travis-ci access dependencies normally found in my local Maven repo?

Tags: maven, github, gradle, travis-ci

I have a GitHub project with a Gradle build. Gradle knows how to look in my local Maven repository when building locally.

How can I tell Travis-CI about these dependencies without including the artifacts in the actual project? The dependencies are private and can't really be pushed to something like maven central for everyone to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either commit the artifacts to a private source control repository, or push them to a private binary repository. The only suitable software-as-a-service binary repository that I'm aware of at this time is [Artifactory Online](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactorycloud_overview). If you go with a binary repository, you'll also have to provide Travis with (temporary) credentials to download the artifacts. One way to do this would be to configure the Travis build to set an environment variable containing the necessary information.

Comment: Okay, I figured that may be the only option. Are there any other hosted solutions you know of that cost less? I really only have a couple of small artifacts.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other. [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) is great in general but doesn't offer private repositories at this time. You could try a private [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (source control) repo, which is free. Then you'll only have to teach Travis how to clone a second repo (or do it in the Gradle build). There might even be a way to use BitBucket as a binary (e.g. Maven) repo. I'm doing the same for my [Expecty](https://github.com/pniederw/expecty) project over on GitHub; see the readme, Gradle build and `m2repo` directory.

Comment: I will probably write a Gradle plugin to pull a jar dependency from a private GitHub repo which I will call mavenRepo :)